# C++ NetBeans - Removing Console from Win32

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I have a Win32 app that displays a console window in the back. How can I, using NetBeans/C++, remove this console window?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific?   Are you running this app in NetBeans?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to go for "Right-Mouse-Button: Properties" in your C/C++ Project, choose "Categories: Run" within the upcoming dialog window. Then find "Console type" within the pane showing off at the right, and there you may try to switch from "Standard output" to "Internal Terminal" entry. Watch out for having the correct "Configuration" at the top of that pane, "Debug" or "Release", respectively. Hope that works for your NetBeans, too. ... Regards, M.